# Probability notation: Can you write f($X=x$) if X is a continuous r.v?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

I'm self teaching myself probability theory and while reading through 'Introduction to Probability' by Blitzstein, I got a question regarding notation.

If Y is a discrete r.v. and X is a continuous r.v., then $P(Y = y|X = x)$ is used in the book and the author briefly talks about why $X = x$ is used here. He says

> "Rigorously speaking, we are actually conditioning on the event that $X$ falls within a small interval of $x$, say $X \in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ and then taking a limit as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$." - p.288

If so, my question is if I can do the same for continuous r.v.s. For example if $Z$ is a continuous r.v., could I say $f_{X,Z}(X=x,Z=z)$ instead of $f_{X,Z}(x,z)$ ?

Comment: That would not be standard notation but the reader would probably understand your intent.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $f(X=x,Z=z)$ then?

Comment: Why would you insert $X=x$ and $Z=z$ as arguments of a function $f_{X,Z}$ defined on $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @Ian Aha, then it's not prohibited I guess? I'll probably stick to the standard notation but I was just wondering if it's wrong to write it that way - like writing $P(X=x)$ is wrong if $X$ is a continuous r.v.

Comment: @Did Could you elaborate on your comment please? I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. In my example $f_{X,Z}$ is a joint pdf of $X$ and $Z$. Since $X$ and $Z$ can never be exactly equal to $x$ and $z$, I thought I'm not allowed to write $f(X=x,Z=z)$ which I'm curious to know about.

Comment: Again, the arguments of the function $f_{X,Z}$ are numbers, not events, but $X=x$ and $Z=z$ are events, not numbers, so inserting the latter in the former can have no meaning. (Note that I am **repeating** here, not **elaborating**.)

Comment: @Did Ohh! You're totally right haha that makes perfect sense thank you!

EDIT: I'm sorry to bug you again, but in the book, $f_Y(y|X=x)$ is used where $Y$ is continuous and $X$ is discrete. I guess this is allowed because you're inputting just y and $X = x$ is the event that we're conditioning on?

Comment: Sorry but I see no point in this kind of mediocre notations, except as a possible source of confusion. A sound notation would be something like $$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$$

Answer (score 0):

No, don't write $f_X(x)=f(X=x)$ because the right-hand side does not make clear sense. Instead, for a continuous R.V. you can write
$$F_X(x)=P(X\leqslant x)$$
where $F_X(x)$ is the CDF.